# keep suggestion box div relative to input when zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this form in a table and one of the text inputs has a suggestion box. when the page is zoomed out to 90% the suggestion box div moves about 6 pixels down and right. is there any way to keep the div in the same position when zooming? thanks. here is a [jsfiddle to demonstate](http://jsfiddle.net/xLw4b/)

html:

```
table {
        border:1px solid grey;
      }

#box {
       border:1px solid red; 
       width:150px; 
       position:absolute; 
       top:35px; 
       left:41px; 
       background-color:white;
     }

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td><input></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>two</td>
    <td><input type = "button" id = "showBox" value = "click then zoom out"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id = "box" style = "display:none;">
  <ul>
    <li>now zoom out</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#showBox').click(function(){
   $('#box').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLw4b/1/)

Moved the box in the corresponding `<td>`. There is still some flickering though, but it's better than before. Hope it fits your standards :)